# Relative reference path to a dll to keep from copying dlls

Tags: c#, relative-path, .net-assembly

I wrote a dll in c# 2010 that utilizes third party dlls. When I add the references to these dlls it copies them all over to the local directory.

I wrote a small application that uses my dll. When I add the reference to my dll, it copies all the dlls over to the local directory again.

How can I get my dll to reference the third party dlls, and then my application to reference my dll, without copying everything over and over again? I tried using some relative references, but couldn't get it to work.

This is made more tricky because I need to be able to deploy my app (with my dll) to another computer with the third party dlls installed. I was hoping there was a way to simply tell vs2010 that I do not want to copy the dlls, rather I want to reference them relatively depending on where the host computer has the third party dlls already copied.

I can't seem to make that happen.

***Clarification

Currently when I deploy the app, all the dlls I reference are in my application folder. So now the dll files are in my application folder and the third party folder on the machine. Is there a way to get the application to just find the dll files that are already on the computer and reference them?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy, the Windows Installer will check the existing DLL files, and will not copy your dll files (or those of the third party) unless they are newer.

This is a good thing.

Comment: Is there a way to keep it from copying the dlls at all? I mean currently, if I deploy my project, it has the dlls in my application folder AND the third party dlls are already in their own folder on the machine. This means there are two copies of the dlls. I want to make it so that there are only one set of dll files on the machine.